# Ajax preloader for SWF files.. is it possible?

Tags: javascript, ajax, flash, preloader

I am looking for a javascript based preloader that can handle .SWF (flash) files.

I'm very much aware that it is possible to preload a flash file by using another flash file, but I was wondering if anyone knows about an AJAX preloader that can load swfs (also, a progressEvent would be a nice extra) and then add the flash file to the HTML document.

I did quite some googling but it seems that there is no such thing out there. Is it überhaupt possible ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Well, nothing impossible: Load SWF on a hidden div, and provide additional external interface in SWF for progress monitoring, so that your SWF can report upload progress via external method or a callback. When it's done downloading, you can just show this DIV, or load it in another DIV, and it will be loaded from cache.

Comment: the problem with this solution is that the SWF can not communicate with the external interface until it is fully loaded.

Comment: Yeah, what if you use external preloader?

Comment: then I am still using an SWF to load another SWF :)